# Doctrine 2: What does getResult return when there are no rows? null?

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I wonder what is returned by functions like `get*Result()`. It seems like null? Where in the docs can I find such info?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`get*Result()` methods return an empty `array()`
`getSingle*Result()` methods throw a `\Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException`

Here are direct links to the doctrine API docs

- `getResult()` [doctrine API docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.6/Doctrine/ORM/AbstractQuery.html#method_getResult)
- `getSingleResult()` [doctrine API docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.6/Doctrine/ORM/AbstractQuery.html#method_getSingleResult)
- `getSingleScalarResult()` [doctrine API docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.6/Doctrine/ORM/AbstractQuery.html#method_getSingleScalarResult)
- `getOneOrNullResult()` [doctrine API docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.6/Doctrine/ORM/AbstractQuery.html#method_getOneOrNullResult)

Also important exceptions:

- `NoResultException` [doctrine API docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.6/Doctrine/ORM/NoResultException.html)
- `NonUniqueResultException`  [doctrine API docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.6/Doctrine/ORM/NonUniqueResultException.html)

  (must handle for `getSingle*()` and `getOneOrNullResult()` methods)
- `UnexpectedResultException`  [doctrine API docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.6/Doctrine/ORM/UnexpectedResultException.html) (this is parent exception of the two above)

> direct links are for 2.6, but you can find there more recent versions at the at http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/index.html